# AngularJS + Karma + Jasmine - Testing a private function

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

I am trying to test a function which is a private function, and it is been called in some other function in my controller. When I try to test this validateParameterGroup function, it gives an error saying that validateParameterGroup is not defined.

**controller**

```
angular.module('PpmApp')
.controller('parameterGroupListController', ['$scope', '$injector', 'parameterGroups', parameterGroupListController]);

  function parameterGroupListController($scope, $injector, parameterGroups) {
    $scope.createParameterGroup = function (parameterGroup) {
      var validationErrors = validateParameterGroup(parameterGroup);
    }
    function validateParameterGroup(parameterGroup) {
     // ...
    }
};
```

**Test Case**

```
describe('validateParameterGroup', function () {
  beforeEach(function () {
    var parameterGroup = {};
  });
  it('should validate a parameter group', function () {
   expect(validateParameterGroup(parameterGroup)).toEqual(false);
  });
 });
```

============ Edit ==================

If it is not possible to test a private function, Can I test $scope.createParameterGroup? I tried doing this but I am getting following error.

> TypeError: $scope.createParameterGroup(...) is not a function

**Test**

```
describe('createParameterGroup', function() {
  var validationErrors, parameterGroup;
  beforeEach(function() {
    validationErrors = {};
    validationErrors.isError;
    parameterGroup = {
      GroupName: "ABC",
      Description: "ABC",
      fromMonth: 1,
      fromYear: 18,
      toMonth: 12,
      toYear: 18
    }
  });

  it('should create a parameter group', function() {
    expect($scope.createParameterGroup(parameterGroup)(validationErrors.isError)).toEqual(false);
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you show the entiere controller please?

Comment: @zooly I have updated the code, please have a look

Comment: This is what I thought! See VadimB answer, your function is not linked to `$scope`, it is private, so unacessible to Karma.

Comment: Making function public does not seems to be a solution though. is there any alternative?

Comment: Honestly I don't know, maybe by binding it to `this`.
You cant do `$scope.validateParameterGroup(...)`?

Comment: @zooly yes I cant do $scope.validateParameterGroup(), and for a good reason. so looking for alternatives.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165142/discussion-between-nilesh-mahajan-and-zooly).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `validateParameterGroup` becomes fully private and not accessible from outside. You can extend `$scope` object to include this function to become public, similar to `createParameterGroup`

```
angular.module('PpmApp')
.controller('parameterGroupListController', ['$scope', '$injector', 'parameterGroups', parameterGroupListController]);

  function parameterGroupListController($scope, $injector, parameterGroups) {
    $scope.createParameterGroup = function (parameterGroup) {
      var validationErrors = validateParameterGroup(parameterGroup);
    }

    $scope.validateParameterGroup = function(parameterGroup) {
     // ...
    }
};
```

Comment: Is there any alternative? as I am not comfortable with making validateParameterGroup function to be public.

Comment: you need to make smth public, so can wrap `validateParameterGroup` with function like `validate` and make it public. Like `scope.validate = function(params) { 
return validateParameterGroup(params) }` and then mock overall `validate`

Comment: how if I test $scope.createparameterGroup function and by doing it will automatically tet my validateParameterGroup function?

Comment: check out the following link, I have posted a solution to above problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48811341/angularjs-jasmin-testing-a-function-wchich-does-not-return-anything-but-call