# AngularJs + Jasmin : testing a function wchich does not return anything but calls another function for validation and a factory service

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I am trying to test this createParameterGroup function which is calling a private function, When I try to test this createParameterGroup function, it gives an error saying that validateParameterGroup is not a function.

**controller**

```
angular.module('PpmApp')
.controller('parameterGroupListController', ['$scope', '$injector', 'parameterGroups', parameterGroupListController]);

  function parameterGroupListController($scope, $injector, parameterGroups) {
    $scope.createParameterGroup = function (parameterGroup) {
      var validationErrors = validateParameterGroup(parameterGroup);
      if (validationErrors.isError) return;
      parameterGroupApiService.createParameterGroup(parameterGroup);
    }
    function validateParameterGroup(parameterGroup) {
      var validationErrors = {};
      validationErrors.isError = false;
     // Validations goes here
     return validationErrors;
    }
};
```

**Test**

```
describe('createParameterGroup', function() {
  var validationErrors, parameterGroup;
  beforeEach(function() {
    validationErrors = {};
    validationErrors.isError;
    parameterGroup = {
      GroupName: "ABC",
      Description: "ABC",
      fromMonth: 1,
      fromYear: 18,
      toMonth: 12,
      toYear: 18
    }
  });

  it('should create a parameter group', function() {
    expect($scope.createParameterGroup(parameterGroup)).toEqual(false);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending some time around how to write test cases right, I figured it out that I was doing expecting the wrong condition to evaluate the correct output. So this is how I have done it now.

**Test Cases**

```
describe('createParameterGroup', function() {

  it('with blank name returns error message of property name can not be blank', function() {
    var parameterGroup = {
      name: "",
      description: "sss",
      fromMonth: 1,
      fromYear: 18,
      toMonth: 12,
      toYear: 18
    };
    $scope.createParameterGroup(parameterGroup);
    for (var property in parameterGroup) {
      if (!parameterGroup[property] && property != 'description') {
        var propertyName = (property == 'name') ? 'Parameter group name' : property;
      }
      return property;
    }
    expect($scope.createPopupInfo.validationErrors.isError).toEqual(true);
    expect($scope.createPopupInfo.validationErrors[property]).toEqual(propertyName + ' ' + constantsProvider.validationMessages.blankField);
  });

  it('with special characters returns error message of invalid parameter group name', function() {
    var parameterGroup = {
      name: "/*&",
      description: "ABC",
      fromMonth: 1,
      fromYear: 18,
      toMonth: 12,
      toYear: 18
    };
    $scope.createParameterGroup(parameterGroup);
    expect($scope.createPopupInfo.validationErrors.isError).toEqual(true);
    expect($scope.createPopupInfo.validationErrors.name).toEqual('Parameter group name \'' + parameterGroup.name + '\' ' + constantsProvider.validationMessages.specialCharacters);
  });

  it('with invalid effective time period returns error message of Invalid effective time period', function() {
    var parameterGroup = {
      name: "ABC",
      description: "ABC",
      fromMonth: 5,
      fromYear: 18,
      toMonth: 4,
      toYear: 18
    };
    $scope.createParameterGroup(parameterGroup);
    expect($scope.createPopupInfo.validationErrors.isError).toEqual(true);
    expect($scope.createPopupInfo.validationErrors.toYear).toEqual(constantsProvider.validationMessages.effectiveTimePeriod);
  });

  it('with valid input returns the given input back without any error message', function() {

    var parameterGroup = {
      GroupName: "ABC",
      Description: "sss",
      EffectiveStartDateTime: 1 / 18,
      EffectiveEndDateTime: 12 / 18
    };
    var createResponse = {};
    createResponse.IsSuccess = true;

    spyOn(parameterGroupApiService, 'createParameterGroup').and.callFake(function() {
      return {
        then: function(callback) {
          return callback(createResponse);
        }
      }
    });

    spyOn(parameterGroupApiService, 'getParameterGroups').and.callFake(function() {
      return {
        then: function(callback) {
          callback(parameterGroup);
          return {
            catch: function() {}
          }
        }
      }
    });

    $scope.createParameterGroup(parameterGroup);

    expect($scope.createPopupInfo.validationErrors.isError).toEqual(false);
    expect(parameterGroupApiService.createParameterGroup).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(parameterGroupApiService.getParameterGroups).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect($scope.parameterGroups).toBe(parameterGroup);
  });


});
```